# File upload only format is JPEG and PDF with current code working perfectly fine in Firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Currently working on file upload with my current code current code working perfectly fine in Mozilla Firefox but not in Google Chrome.

If I click the `view` link it will open in a new window but if I try to upload pdf files, when I click the `view` link it won't open.

**jQuery Code:**

```
var $preview = $(".preview");
$preview.hide();
 $("input").on("change", function() {
  var files = this.files;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(e) {
    $preview.attr("href", e.target.result);
    $preview.show();
  };
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
});
```

Here is the JSbin [Link](http://jsbin.com/pomeqa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Its working for `pdf` as well..I am using `Firefox 41.x.x`?

Comment: Yes it was not working only in google chrome :)

Comment: @Mahadevan hi not working in 36.x.x version in FireFox

Comment: Your code works fine if I try it locally, certainly something to do with iframe security in JSbin

Comment: I tried it was not working in local also :(

Comment: Ah in that case, can't repro on Chrome 44.0 on mac, but for this you may want to use `var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);`, no need for a fileReader at all.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nukowukema/edit?html,js,output

Comment: hi @Kaiido thank you so much for your support is that possible can i able to save the file in server

Comment: well if you want to save it as a file, use a `Formdata.append('your_file', files[0])` and send it through xhr. If you want to save the dataURL, go back to your first solution, I still don't know why it's not working on your machine, but since it does on mine, can't help further